# Exception message when trying to load data to DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, exception, datagridview

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SQLCONTROL
    Private DBcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-DQ7NOIF\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True")
    Private DBcom As New SqlCommand

    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ConnctionString As String)
        DBcon = New SqlConnection(ConnctionString)

    End Sub

    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            DBcon.Open()
            DBcom = New SqlCommand(Query, DBcon)
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBcom.Parameters.Add(p))
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBcom)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error" & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            If DBcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBcon.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Exception:")
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

the exception message is "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Nom d'objet 'Utilisateurs' non valide."

thanks

Comment: Despite your having posted a French error message without translation, it appears that you're being told that the database object name `Utilisateurs` is not valid. There appears to be an issue with your SQL code but that is one thing that you haven't shown us. I suggest that you check any table and column names in your SQL code to ensure that they are all correct.

Comment: For future reference, the title should be a concise summary of your issue. Don't include greetings or descriptions of your level of expertise. Also, the exception here appears to be when executing a query so the `DataGridView` has no relevance. Finally, the site provides a preview of your post for a reason. Make sure you use it and don't submit if your code formatting is not correct. If you don't know how to format code properly, make the effort to find out before posting.

Comment: This is a good idea to separate the User Interface code from the data access code but you are forcing your ui code to know about Sql Server. I suspect you are checking a user login since you are not returning any data just a record count. You need specific methods to handle different types of  queries.

Answer (score 0):

Many database objects (including connections and commands) expose a `.Dispose` method which means that they may be using unmanaged resources which need to be released. To guarantee that `.Dispose` is called .net provides `Using...End Using`.

Any errors will bubble up to the calling code where you can handle them and inform the user. After all, your class could be used in a web app or phone app where `MsgBox` would not work. Leave informing the user to the User Interface code.

```
Public Class SQLCONTROL

    Private ConStr As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-DQ7NOIF\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True"

    Public Function IsUserValid(userName As String, password As String) As Boolean
        Dim RetVal As Integer
        Using DBcon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                DBcom As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From [Utilisateurs] Where UserName = @UserName And Password = @Password;", DBcon)
            DBcom.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = userName
            DBcom.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = password
            DBcon.Open()
            RetVal = CInt(DBcom.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
        If RetVal = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

    'To return a DataTable for a DataGridView
    Public Function GetCustomerOrders(Customer As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using DBcon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                DBcom As New SqlCommand("Select * From Orders Where CustomerName = @CustomerName;", DBcon)
            DBcom.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Customer
            DBcon.Open()
            dt.Load(DBcom.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class
```

Usage in Form

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sql As New SQLCONTROL
    If sql.IsUserValid("Mary", "MySecretPassword") Then
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim sql As New SQLCONTROL
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sql.GetCustomerOrders("General Motors")
End Sub
```

Naturally, I only guessed at field names, types, and sizes. Check your database.

In a real application you would never store passwords as plain text.